# Как добавить добавлять 1 элемент строки, исключая пробелы?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Входные данные**: На вход подаётся последовательность чисел.(Пример 1 2 3).
Необходимо добавить все элементы в массив, исключая пробелы между ними.

**Моя реализация**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string st;
    getline(cin, st);
    int len_st = (st.size());
    int count = 0;
    char *word = new char[len_st];
    char x;
    for (int i = 0; i <= len_st; i ++) {
        count += 1;
        if (st[i] != " ") {
            x = st[i];
            word[i] = x;
        }
    }
    delete[] word;
}
```

Пытался реализовать вот так, но комплиятор ругается на сравнение `st[i] != " "`.
Подскажите, как можно по другому реализовать подобный алгоритм или укажите на ошибку в моей реализации.

Comment: `st[i] != ' '`.

Comment: и заметьте, что в массиве будут отдельные цифры, а не числа целиком- например, 42 запишется в два символа

Comment: 1. Массив или можно вектор? 2. Числа с разделителями-пробелами, или все цифры отдельно?

Comment: Если на вход даётся последовательность чисел, то у них пробелов быть не может. Добавить в массив какого типа : строк или чисел? Целочисленных или с запятыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас метка `c++11`, так что я бы написал как-нибудь вот так:

```
std::vector<int> splitString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    auto begin = str.begin();
    auto end = begin;
    while (end != str.end())
    {
        // находим первый не пробельный символ
        begin = std::find_if(begin, str.end(), [](char c) -> bool{
            return c != ' ';
        });
        if (begin == str.end()) // если не нашли, выходим, тут больше ловить нечего
            break;
        end = std::find(begin, str.end(), ' '); // находим следующий пробельный символ
        std::string_view word(&*begin, std::distance(begin, end)); // это и будет очередное число
        result.push_back(std::stoi(word.data()));   // тут не помешала бы обработка ошибок
        begin = end;    // готовимся искать следующее число
    }
    return result;
}
```